# Redis how node return True in function async/await

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, node-redis

forgive me the question.
I'm not used to node and sync / await

I have the following function which queries a mongodb returning a json, I'm saving that return on redis.
So far so good.

```
findLightnings: async (request, h) => {
    const q = request.query.q.split(':');
    const index = q[0];
    const value = q[1].split(',');

    const dateInit = new Date(request.query.dateInit);
    const dateEnd = new Date(request.query.dateEnd);
    const page = request.query.page;
    const distance = request.query.distance;
    const redis = require('redis');
    const client = redis.createClient();

    let limit = 300;

    let filter = {
      $and: [{
        data: {
          $gte: dateInit.toISOString(),
          $lte: dateEnd.toISOString()
        }
      }]
    }

    if (index === 'latlng') {
      filter['$and'][0]['geo.coordinates'] = {
        $near: {
          $geometry: {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: value.map(Number),
            $minDistance: 0,
            $maxDistance: distance
          }
        }
      }
      limit = 100;
    } else {
      filter['$and'][0][`cidade.${index}`] = {
        $in: value
      }
    }

    return client.get('elektro', async (err, reply) => {
    let resp = null;

    if (reply) {
        console.log(reply); //<<<<<<<< Return Json OK
        resp = reply // <<<<<<<<<< Return TRUE in json's place
    } else {
        console.log('db')
        const query = await Lightning.find(filter).sort('data').skip(page*limit).limit(limit).exec();
        client.set('elektro', JSON.stringify(query));
        client.expire('elektro', 3600);
        resp = query
    }

    return JSON.stringify(resp);
  })
  }
```

The problem is time to recover this data from the redis.
In the console log json appears normal, how much tento returns that value for the main function it comes 'TRUE' and not the json saved in redis.

Someone can give me a helping hand on this.
I really need this function.

Comment: Your function `findLightnings()` is returning the result of `client.get()` not `JSON.stringify(resp)`. `JSON.stringify(resp)` is only returned to the callback. Might be worth looking at `client.getAsync()`

Comment: Thanks @mark-meyer, your response has opened my mind. I researched more about the `client.getAsync` solution and found what I was looking for.

Very successful to you.
I'll post as the code was at the end, I believe I can improve, but the main problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem with the redis client.getAsync().

which already has a native async function:
source: [Node-redis](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis)

The final code is as follows:

```
 findLightnings: async (request, h) => {
     const q = request.query.q.split(':');
     const index = q[0];
     const value = q[1].split(',');

     const dateInit = new Date(request.query.dateInit);
     const dateEnd = new Date(request.query.dateEnd);
     const page = request.query.page;
     const distance = request.query.distance;

     let limit = 300;

     let filter = {
       $and: [{
         data: {
           $gte: dateInit.toISOString(),
           $lte: dateEnd.toISOString()
         }
       }]
     }

     if (index === 'latlng') {
       filter['$and'][0]['geo.coordinates'] = {
         $near: {
           $geometry: {
             type: 'Point',
             coordinates: value.map(Number),
             $minDistance: 0,
             $maxDistance: distance
           }
         }
       }
       limit = 100;
     } else {
       filter['$and'][0][`cidade.${index}`] = {
         $in: value
       }
     }

    return getAsync('findLightnings'+ '/' + request.query.q + '/' + request.query.dateInit + '/' + request.query.dateEnd).then(async (res) => {
        if(res){
          console.log('Fonte Dados => redis')
          return res
        }else{
          console.log('Fonte Dados => db')
           try {
             const query = await Lightning.find(filter).sort('data').exec();//.skip(page*limit).limit(limit).exec();
             client.set('findLightnings'+ '/' + request.query.q + '/' + request.query.dateInit + '/' + request.query.dateEnd, JSON.stringify(query));
             return query;
           } catch (err) {
             return Boom.badData(err);
           }
        }
        client.close();
      });
   },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const redis = require('redis');

const client = redis.createClient(6379);

const bluebird = require("bluebird");
```

bluebird.promisifyAll(redis.RedisClient.prototype);

bluebird.promisifyAll(redis.Multi.prototype);

```
const redisdata = await client.getAsync("user:photos");

if (redisdata) {

        console.log(`cache EXISTS`)

        return res.json({ source: 'cache', data: JSON.parse(redisdata) })

    }
```